# Função imprimir lista circular

Tags: c

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida de onde e como devo mudar para essa função de imprimir lista circular fique correta.

Está abaixo é uma função imprimir de uma lista ligada:

```
void imprime_lista(tipo_lista* p)
{
while (p != NULL)
{
    printf("%d\n", p->info);
    p = p -> prox;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só muda que o critério de parada do laço de repetição vai ser quando chegar ao primeiro. É necessário também trocar o `while`por `do`, porque a lista já começa no primeiro elemento e com o `while` não irá imprimir nada.

```
void imprime_lista(tipo_lista* p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
        return;
    tipo_lista* primeiro = p;
    do
    {
        printf("%d\n", p->info);
        p = p -> prox;
    }while(p != primeiro);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, porém deu a mensagem de o programa parou de funcionar, na `main`estou chamando `imprime_lista(p);`

Comment: Talvez convenha verificar antes de entrar no `do {} while` se `primeiro` não é `NULL` e pôr `(p && p != primeiro)` como critério de parada; assim, se `p` for vazia ou não for uma lista circular de  verdade, a função não se perde.

Comment: Se passar uma lista vazia o programa vai dar erro mesmo. Adicionei um if para corrigir isso. Outra coisa que pode estar causando o erro é que uma lista que não é circular foi passada.

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa

Comment: Provavelmente sua lista circular está errada em algum ponto

Comment: Da uma olhada por favor: https://pastebin.com/9VKC7uBK

Comment: A função de inserir está errada, ela está inserindo como uma lista simples e não como circular, então depois do último elemento a lista vai para NULL e é onde o erro acontece.

Comment: @LucasTrigueiro eu mudei a função inserir, o atual código está assim: [códigocompleto]: https://pastebin.com/GBd9xjCH   Agora não sei onde está acontecendo o erro se é na função imprime ou insere. Se você executar não sai nada na tela. Valeu.

Comment: O erro é na insere, porque você verifica se é null e retorna e como a lista começa em null o programa nunca vai sair disso.